# Java regular expression to match a alphanumeric string of length greater than one which has atleast one different character

Tags: java, regex

In the below regular expression

```
^(?:(?!(\w)\1\b).)*$
```

Does not match string which has last two characters same. For example 1233

What is the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please narrow your question down to a specific coding problem that would be on-topic for this site.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Comment: Normally I would respond to a question like this by suggesting that you show code and explain where you're having a problem. However, your requirement of "at least one different character" is not supported by regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I have refined the question. Please make this question as active

Answer (score 1):

If you want to (not) match the same character, [try the following code](http://ideone.com/hk96P5):

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    final String SAME_CHAR = "(.)\\1*";
    final List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("Apple","Aa", "A1a", "AAg");
    final List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("AAA", "111", "aaaaa", "a");

    for (String str: list1) {
        System.out.println(str + ": " + !str.matches(SAME_CHAR));
    }
    for (String str: list2) {
        System.out.println(str + ": " + !str.matches(SAME_CHAR));
    }
}
```

The resulting output would be:

```
Apple: true
Aa: true
A1a: true
AAg: true
AAA: false
111: false
aaaaa: false
a: false
```

Comment: Found solution. /^(? :(?! (\\w) \\1\\b).)*$/

Comment: Well, congratulations on the so much cleaner looking regex ;-)